# CSS flexbox. Achieve this grid on Safari 6

Tags: css, flexbox, safari6, grid-system

I read that Safari 6 has partial support for flexbox but I am not exactly sure what is missing.

My goal is to create a grid that has the possibility of fixed side columns mixed with liquid columns.

e.g:

`| 256px fixed width | this column has width:100% and spans rest of space |`

Here is an example working in latest stable Chrome, FF, Opera, IE10. Unfortunately this fails in Safari 6 though which seems to completely ignore the flexbox stuff.

Is there some css tweak I can make to get it working, or an alternative?

**Demo/code:** http://dominictobias.com/grid/with-fixed.html (< 767px it will stack, which AFAIK is not achievable without flex when mixing liquid and fixed columns)

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.row { 
    width: 2560px; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    min-width: 320px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row.fixed {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.row .row { 
    width: auto; 
    max-width: none; 
    min-width: 0; 
    margin: 16px -16px; 
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row .col { 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: 16px;
}

.row .span-1 { width: 4.167%; }
.row .span-2 { width: 8.333%; }
.row .span-3 { width: 12.5%; }
.row .span-4 { width: 16.667%; }
.row .span-5 { width: 20.833%; }
.row .span-6 { width: 25%; }
.row .span-7 { width: 29.167%; }
.row .span-8 { width: 33.333%; }
.row .span-9 { width: 37.5%; }
.row .span-10 { width: 41.667%; }
.row .span-11 { width: 45.833%; }
.row .span-12 { width: 50%; }
.row .span-13 { width: 54.167%; }
.row .span-14 { width: 58.333%; }
.row .span-15 { width: 62.5%; }
.row .span-16 { width: 66.667%; }
.row .span-17 { width: 70.833%; }
.row .span-18 { width: 75%; }
.row .span-19 { width: 79.167%; }
.row .span-20 { width: 83.333%; }
.row .span-21 { width: 87.5%; }
.row .span-22 { width: 91.667%; }
.row .span-23 { width: 95.833%; }
.row .span-24 { width: 100%; }

.row .fixed-256 { 
    -webkit-flex: 1 256px;
    -moz-flex: 1 256px;
    -ms-flex: 1 256px;
    flex: 1 256px;
}

.row .fixed-content { 
    -webkit-flex: 1 99 100%;
    -moz-flex: 1 99 100%;
    -ms-flex: 1 99 100%;
    flex: 1 99 100%;
}

.row .offset-1 { margin-left: 4.167%; }
.row .offset-2 { margin-left: 8.333%; }
.row .offset-3 { margin-left: 12.5%; }
.row .offset-4 { margin-left: 16.667%; }
.row .offset-5 { margin-left: 20.833%; }
.row .offset-6 { margin-left: 25%; }
.row .offset-7 { margin-left: 29.167%; }
.row .offset-8 { margin-left: 33.333%; }
.row .offset-9 { margin-left: 37.5%; }
.row .offset-10 { margin-left: 41.667%; }
.row .offset-11 { margin-left: 45.833%; }
.row .offset-12 { margin-left: 50%; }
.row .offset-13 { margin-left: 54.167%; }
.row .offset-14 { margin-left: 58.333%; }
.row .offset-15 { margin-left: 62.5%; }
.row .offset-16 { margin-left: 66.667%; }
.row .offset-17 { margin-left: 70.833%; }
.row .offset-18 { margin-left: 75%; }
.row .offset-19 { margin-left: 79.167%; }
.row .offset-20 { margin-left: 83.333%; }
.row .offset-21 { margin-left: 87.5%; }
.row .offset-22 { margin-left: 91.667%; }
.row .offset-23 { margin-left: 95.833%; }
.row .offset-24 { margin-left: 100%; }

.show-grid .row {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.show-grid .col {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: rgba(70,61,180,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(70,61,180,.2);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row { 
        width: auto; 
        min-width: 0; 
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .row.fixed {
        display: block;
    }
    .row .col {
        width: auto !important; 
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row .col:last-child { 
        float: none; 
    }
    .row .col:before,
    .row .col:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .row .col:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-16">
        This column spans 16
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-12">
                This nested column spans 12
            </div>
            <div class="col span-12">
                This nested column spans 12
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
                    <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
                    <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
                    <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-8">
        This column spans 8
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row fixed">
    <div class="col fixed-256">
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
    </div>
    <div class="col fixed-content span-24">
        This column spans the rest of the width and consists of 24 columns
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row fixed">
    <div class="col fixed-256">
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
        This is a fixed 256px column
    </div>
    <div class="col fixed-content span-24">
        This column spans the rest of the width and consists of 24 columns
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
            <div class="col span-6">6 column</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col fixed-256">
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
        This is a fixed right 256px column
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col offset-6 span-10">
        This column spans 10, and is offseted by 6
    </div>

    <div class="col offset-5 span-3">
        This column spans 3, and is offseted by 5
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide code with your question.

Comment: The html/css is on that single html I because it is a bit long didnt want to post it but I'll put the css up and bit of the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need flexbox for this. Here's a clever trick that can be used to achieve exactly that:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

You may have multiple floats and may even have multiple variable width element, as long as you wrap them in a container and use percentages on them.

(In case the article goes offline: The trick is to float the fixed-width element and then use `display: block` and `overflow: hidden` (or `auto`) on the variable width element. Setting `overflow` actually makes the block stay clear of the float. Many times this trick can be used instead of resorting to `calc()`.)

Comment: Ah good point @dalgard. I have used that for images next to text but not thought of it for layouts! Shame it limits to two columns (I think) but nice idea nontheless

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, you can have any number of fixed width floats, and you can wrap the variable stuff in a container with `display: block`